# Can you use the Sandy Bridge H67 IGP and an additional graphics card to drive 2 monitors via DisplayPort?

Tags: video, graphics-card, displayport, sandy-bridge, igp

I'm going to build a new pc. I want it to be connected to my two monitors via DisplayPort because the other ports on the monitors are already in use by another computer.

I'm thinking about going with a Sandy Bridge H67 board, that will give me one DisplayPort connector on board when I combine it with a K series processor.

Would I be able to add another video card to the system that also has a DisplayPort connector and connect it to the second monitor? Or will the on board graphics be disabled when you add an additional card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Surfasb said, one or the other. You can however get video cards to two display ports on them... so if you must have two working display ports go for one of those (then you don't need to be as picky out your motherboard either, if that helps any.)

Comment: From reading the motherboard manual of the ASRock Z68 Pro3-M motherboard it appears that it is possible (using IGP and additional card at the same time) with the Z68 chipset but apperantly it is not possible with the H67 chipset.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has to be one or the other.